# jquery superslides vertical height issue

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a plugin called jquery Superslides (https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides) which in general works very well, however I am getting stuck with one tricky problem. Content which is taller than the window is causing the background images not to cover the whole screen, as in the example here: http://fantasyhighstreet.org.uk/index.php?page=crystal-palace-2015

The menu on the left is contained in a Div which is overlaid on top of the slider and uses absolute positioning, so a vertical scrollbar appears if the window height cannot accommodate the height of the menu box. If one scrolls down, there is an ugly white space where the slide background image stops.

I have tried using fixed positioning for the menu div, however this results in no visible scroll bar and the menu box disappearing off the bottom of the window if it is not high enough.

Is there a way to have vertically- scrolled content which doesn't result in the slide images being cut off?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To acheive what you want , you must have your left menu with scroll when needed.

**CSS**

```
.leftbox {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: auto;
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 0.9; 
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: auto; // Set this
  bottom: 20px; // Set this - adjust your needs
}
```

Comment: don´t forget the `bottom: 20px;` adjust your needs